# GUI window is not appearing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to learn to use gui in java using eclipse ide.
When I run this code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello "+name);
        
    }   
}
```

all it shows is terminated GUI [Java Application]

How can I fix this issue?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbe54.png)

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. In the _Console_ view, `<terminated> GUI [Java Application]` is only displayed after the message dialog _"Hello ..."_ has been closed. If you have more than one `GUI.java` file, make sure you are looking at the right one.

Comment: @DevilsHnd-退した i just click on run but it does not show any gui window.

Comment: @howlger I don't have anything else open while running the code. When I run it, it gets terminated on its own without doing anything.

Comment: time to debug... set a breakpoint at the first statement inside `main` (double-click left of line) and click on Debug instead of Run - a message about opening the Debug Perspective should appear (or the perspective is automatically opened) and the code should be started but stop at the line with the breakpoint - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAldL.png) || poor-mans alternative: add a `System.out.println("starting...");` as first line of `main`

Comment: ( to be sure that the correct code is being executed, you can also right-click inside the editor window with that code and select "Run As" and then "Java Application" )

Comment: According to your screenshot, you are using Java 22 which has been released 12 days ago and is not yet supported by Eclipse (there is only a [preview/alpha version of the Java 22 support provided via the Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-22-support-eclipse-2024-03-431)). Better stick to Java 21, 17, 11 or 8 for which you get long term support.